# JQuery: How to show/hide a series of form labels onde after another

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to make a stream of show / hide fields in a form with jQuery.

This is the form:

```
<form>
    <label for="onde" class="onde">
        <b>qua qua text</b>
        <textarea name="onde" id="onde"></textarea>
        <a class="next">Continue</a>
    </label>

    <label for="tentou">
        <b>bla bla text</b>
        <textarea name="tentou" id="tentou"></textarea>
        <a class="next">Continue</a>
    </label>

    <label for="quase">
        <b>yada yada text</b>
        <textarea name="quase" id="quase"></textarea>
    </label>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

So, when I click on a.next, I need to hide the label of which the anchor tag belongs and show the next tag.

The problem here is that actually I don't know the labels names (not even the real number of labels in the form), for they will be dynamically generated.

The last task will be make the submit bottom show when the last label will be visible.

Till now this is what I got:

```
$('a.next').click(function(event) {
    $(this).fadeIn('slow');
    $(this).css('display','block');
});
```

But... I can't go any longer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want..

```
$('a.next').click(function(event) {
    var label = $(this).closest('label');
    label.hide();
    label.nextAll('label:first').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/fhuU4/

Answer (score 1):

Just give a common class to your text areas. Suppose we have given class 'ta'
Now here is the code

```
EDIT:
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=0;
    $(".next").click(function(){
        $("label:eq("+i+")").fadeOut(200);
        i++;
        $("label:eq("+i+")").fadeIn(200);
    });
});
```

This is the jquery code you need. 
[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TrW9f/1/)
This is the working fiddle you need.

Comment: In what context you are trying to use toggle? If you are toggling just the hide and show property, Using hide and show function will be better as if by mistake a textarea is already shown, toggle will hide that textarea. If you are toggling with function, You are free to post the you are thinking of.

Comment: How can I get the same effect I have with: `$(this).fadeIn('slow'); $(this).css('display','block');` with `show()` and `hide()`?

Comment: Sourabh: I'm not sure I understand your question. The toggle function toggles visibility of element(s). So instead of checking if an element is visible or keeping an extra variable for tracking visibility or checking the visibility via a property, it's all done with a simple function call. I can't think of a case when an element would be in a wrong visibility state.

Comment: Well the ral block I am trying to hide and show is label not the textarea element.

Comment: It is not working for me. Would't be easier pick the parent of the anchor and so on?

Comment: @AlekDavis: We are not checking if the element is visible or not, We are just making the display property to none, whether it was already none or not.

Comment: @Roger: You want to change the label then put the common class to labels.

Comment: @Roger: You can also use parent element to traverse the elements, But it will increase overhead on the code of traversing the node.

Comment: I have attached a fiddle, Check it out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3942/discussion-between-sourabh-and-roger)

Comment: The fiddle I have attached is completely working the way you want it to